# How can I document the pk parameter (or other path parameters) with Django REST Swagger?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

Is there a way to document the pk parameter that is automatically generated by Django REST Framework (by extending ViewSet)?

Example function in a ViewSet:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @detail_route(url_path='mypath')
    def myapi(self):
        """
            first_param -- Param 1
        """
        pass
```

If I add a pk parameter in the YAML docstring, I got a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **pk** parameter (or any other path parameter) can be documented using a YAML docstring, as described in the [documentation of Django REST Swagger](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/yaml.html#parameters). For the list of attributes you can refer to the [Swagger documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#524-parameter-object).

Note that you have to specify `paramType: path` for path parameters. To avoid duplicates ending up in your api-docs, you can specify `parameters_strategy: replace` as described [here](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/yaml.html#parameters-strategy).

Example:

```
@detail_route(url_path='mypath')
def myapi(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Endpoint documentation.
    ---
        parameters_strategy: replace
        parameters:
            - name: pk
              description: "Primary Key"
              required: true
              type: string
              paramType: path
    """
```